# How do I stop my Sensor Bin closing as soon as it opens?

Tags: trash-can

I have a [1Home Sensor Bin](https://www.amazon.co.uk/1home-Stainless-Automatic-Sensor-Touchless/dp/B07F66ZSRH). As soon as the automated lid opens, it immediately closes again rather than allowing a delay to put refuse in. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this video from Ideal Home Products](https://youtu.be/GWpeJ6SQPl0), replace the 3x batteries in the head and this problem will immediately resolve.